# debugging templates with GDB

Tags: c++, linux, templates, gdb

My `gdb` is GNU gdb Red Hat Linux (6.3.0.0-1.162.el4rh) and I can't debug templates. How can I debug templates with this debugger?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Code snippets, what you've done, what's not working — all of that could help us to help you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if your problem is just about placing breakpoint in your code. Here is a little snippet

ex: main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void coin(T v)
{
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:

    T bar(T c)
    {
        return c * 2;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo<int> f;
    coin(f.bar(21));
}
```

compile with 
    g++ -O0 -g main.cpp

```
gdb ./a.out
(gdb) b Foo<int>::bar(int)
Breakpoint 2 at 0x804871d: file main.cpp, line 16.
(gdb) b void coin<int>(int)
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804872a: file main.cpp, line 6.
(gdb) r
... debugging start
```

otherwise you could just use

```
(gdb) b main.cpp:16
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a hard time trying to get gdb debugging to
work with templates code using gdb 6.8 with code compiled with gcc version 4.4.1

After ripping my hair for a while, I found that it magically
started working perfectly when I add the -fPIC switch to the g++ compile arguments.

Comment: Hello Bo and Ferd, I am curious to know how -fPIC, i.e., position independent code, has helped you to debug template programs in C++. I will be thankful if you kindly share your insights.