# debug c++ template with gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

When I debug inside a function with template,

1. How do I know which template type the current function is using?

   I tried `p T`. It says gdb cant print a type.
2. How do I break on a particular template type?

   Lets say function `foo<T>(...)` have 2 possible forms, `foo<int>(...)` and `foo<long>(...)` . How do I set a breakpoint so that gdb only pauses on the first one which uses `int`, but not the second one which uses `long`?

Edit: It would be nice if the breakpoint can be set by line number. There are many good reasons for this, eg. the initial part of function may take long to run, the place I wish to debug may be inside an `if` statement etc.

Comment: I did this at work today, I'm pretty sure `b foo<int>` will work... If you do `b foo.cpp:123` (assuming line 123 is the line of `foo<T>` it will set multiple breakpoints for all template variants.

Comment: The template instantiation you are in should be visible in the backtrace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666963/debugging-templates-with-gdb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ptype` rather than `p` to print a type.  With a recent enough (couple of years old) g++ and gdb, this will work.

Consider this source:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct S
{
  S(T t)
  {
    std::cout << t;
  }
};

int main()
{
  S<const char*> s2("hello");
  S<int> s1(23);
  return 0;
}
```

Here I can step into the constructor for `s2` and see `T`:

```
(gdb) ptype T
type = const char *
```

Take a look the current frame:

```
(gdb) frame
#0  S<char const*>::S (this=0x7fffffffe35f, t=0x400940 "hello") at q.cc:8
8       std::cout << t;
```

I can set a breakpoint using the function name given there:

```
(gdb) b S<const char *>::S
Breakpoint 2 at 0x40087a: file q.cc, line 8.
```

Comment: I updated the `ptype` part to print the interesting thing -- namely `ptype T` and not `ptype S`.  A little thinko while writing up the answer.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint by line number, but then the problem is filtering it based on type.  This can be done with a bit of Python scripting; basically you need a new convenience function that examines the type.

Answer (score 13):

To set a breakpoint to all instances use:

```
gdb> rbreak Foo<.*>
```

To only set a breakpoint on a known instance

```
gdb> break Foo<int>
```

You can also use `rbreak Foo<int>` but it makes no sense to use a call witch evaluates regular expressions but you give none :-)

Example Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template < typename T>
T Foo(T t) { return t; }

int main()
{
    std::cout << Foo<int>(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << Foo<std::string>("Hallo") << std::endl;
}
```

Simply compile with debug info:

```
g++ main.cpp -g -o go
```

Run gdb:

```
gdb go
```

And test:

```
gdb> rbreak Foo<int>
gdb> run
gdb> backtrace
gdb> cont
```

As you can see: Only one instance of the template is affected.

In the backtrace you can see which template instance is called:

```
#0  Foo<int> (t=1) at main.cpp:5
#1  0x0000000000400b69 in main () at main.cpp:9
```

As you can see it is `Foo<int>` here.

To answer a comment:
"Is there a way to place a breakpoint in the specific known instance at a certain line?"

Yes!

```
gdb> break main:692
gdb> info break
```

this will return something like

```
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
5       breakpoint     keep y   <MULTIPLE>         
5.1                         y   0x00000000004026db in Foo<int>(int) at main.cpp:692
5.2                         y   0x00000000004027a6 in Foo<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) at main.cpp:692
(gdb)
```

Now you can disable specific instances with:

```
gdb> disable 5.2
```

You can not delete a specific "sub breakpoint". But disable is quite what you need. You can also give a range of instances if you like with e.g.:

```
gdb> disable 5.1-2
```

Comment: Ah, it would be better if `b Foo` would default to all instances same as `rbreak Foo<.*>`.

Comment: Is there a way to place a breakpoint in the specific known instance at a certain line? I.e. something like `b foo.cpp:5` but filter for `Foo<int>`?

Comment: @DanM. I updated my answer. In a short: Yes, you can :-)

Comment: @Klaus thanks! Are there other ways to disable en masse? Range disable is extremely helpful and what I was looking for but in my case simply breaking on a line produced several thousand sub-breakpoints, so any way to automate it (like with rbreak) would be appreciated.